# module not recognizing index variable

Tags: python-3.x, function, module, attributeerror, iterable

> I'd like to return the help text for each function in a given module (for example os).  The code below (Code Block A) returned the following error:
>
> AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'i'

```
#Code block A

import os
for i in dir(os):
    print (help(os.i))
```

> If instead I run the code below (Code Block B), the function name in the ith position is returned at each step in the for loop.

```
#Code block B

for i in dir(os):
    print (i)
```

Q1. Why is the index variable i recognized as "i" in Code Block A "help(os.i)", but not in Code Block B "print(i)?

Q2. Is there a way to call each item in an iterable as a function (something akin to Code Block A) for a given module?

> Thanks in advance for any insights or recommendations.

Comment: I don't agree that the question as originally posted was a duplicate.  Though this may be due to my inexperience dealing directly with classes and programming in this way. The answer provided by jk622 is helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the community. If an answer has helped you solve your problem, you should accept it. See [How does accepting an answer work.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a handful of occasions in python where the `i` variable that would otherwise represent an iterable, is instead treated as the string literal "i".  In those cases, it is best to build a string by adding the iterable (represented by `i`) cast as a string to whatever else you were trying to add it to.  Then you just feed the entire string into the function as needed.

In your particular case:

```
for i in dir(os):
    s = "os." + str(i)
    print(help(s))
```